# Implementing PayPal with Java in Android app is showing "Failed to resolve" errors. What could be the causes and how to resolve them?

Tags: java, android, paypal, lifecycle

Im trying to implement paypal in my android app. Im using java.

implementation 'com.paypal.checkout:android-sdk:0.2.0'

But i get this 3 errors:

Failed to resolve: android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:2.1.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
Failed to resolve: android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:2.1.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app
Failed to resolve: org.jfrog.cardinalcommerce.gradle:cardinalmobilesdk:2.2.4-1
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

I tried to implement this but doesn't fix the problems.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle?hl=es-419#java
`def lifecycle_version = "2.5.1"
def arch_version = "2.1.0"

```
    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"
    // Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"

    // Saved state module for ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"

    // Annotation processor
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
    // alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of lifecycle-compiler
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - helpers for implementing LifecycleOwner in a Service
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - ProcessLifecycleOwner provides a lifecycle for the whole application process
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - ReactiveStreams support for LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - Test helpers for LiveData
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$arch_version"

    // optional - Test helpers for Lifecycle runtime
    testImplementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-testing:$lifecycle_version"`
```